# Spinner default style with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I created a spinner with a simple list of `String []`. Now I had to extend it by its own object, i.e. an `ArrayList<ObjectType>`. I created `ArrayAdapter` and everything works fine, except I lost the default style of my Spinner.

I have a ruler responsible for the style, but when expanded between items does not break, it is simply illegible.

```
s_status_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

How do I get the Spinner to use the system style?

Answer (score 1):

You can use android layout resources like this.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);       
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```